# Least value of $\frac{a^2b^2-2a^2b+2a^2+2ab-2a+1}{a^2b+a}$, where $a,b>0$

Tags: inequality

> Least value of
> $\displaystyle \frac{a^2b^2-2a^2b+2a^2+2ab-2a+1}{a^2b+a},$ where $a,b>0$.

What I try :

Let $\displaystyle k=\frac{(ab+1)^2-2a(ab+1)+2a^2}{a(ab+1)}$

Let $ab+1=x>0$, Then we have

$\displaystyle k=\frac{x^2-2ax+2a^2}{ax}$

$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow x^2-(2a+k)x+2a^2=0$

For real roots, its $D>0$

So $(2a+k)^2-8a^2\geq 0$

$\displaystyle4 a^2 -4ak-4a^2\leq 0$

I did not understand how do I solve it , please have a look , Thanks

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?  Please credit the original source in your question.

Comment: @D.W it is from mock test paper of Jee Mains

Comment: Please [edit] your post to credit the original source.  Comments exist to help you improve your post.  Please don't put additional content in the comments -- instead, revise the original question so it is complete and self-contained and so people don't need to read the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = x/a = b+ 1/a$ then $y > 0$. We have:

$$k = y -2 +  \frac{2}{y} \ge -2 +2\sqrt{y\cdot \frac{2}{y} } = 2(\sqrt{2}-1)\hspace{1cm} \text{(AM-GM inequality)}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $(a,b)$ satisfy:  $b + 1/a = \sqrt{2}$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there.

$$\displaystyle k=\frac{(ab+1)^2-2a(ab+1)+2a^2}{a(ab+1)}$$

Let $ab+1=x>1$, then we have

$$ k=\frac{x^2-2ax+2a^2}{ax}$$

This is nicely homogenous (all terms are to the same power of x and a). Let $y=x/a >0$, then

$$k=y-2+\frac2{y}$$

By AM-GM, $y+\frac2{y} \geqslant 2\sqrt2$

$$k\geqslant  2\sqrt2 -2$$

Answer (score 2):

**A solution using discriminant.**

Let $k :=\frac{a^2b^2-2a^2b+2a^2+2ab-2a+1}{a^2b+a}$.
We have
$$a^2b^2-2a^2b+2a^2+2ab-2a+1 = ka^2b + ka$$
or
$$a^2b^2 + ( - 2a^2 + 2a -a^2k)b + 2a^2  - 2a + 1 - ka = 0. \tag{1}$$

From (1) and $a, b > 0$, clearly we have $k > - 2$.
(1) is a quadratic in $b$ whose discriminant is non-negative, i.e.
$$( - 2a^2 + 2a -a^2k)^2 - 4\cdot a^2 \cdot (2a^2  - 2a + 1 - ka)\ge 0$$
or
$$a^4(k^2 + 4k - 4)\ge 0$$
which yields (using $k > -2$)
$$k \ge 2\sqrt{2} - 2.$$

Also, when $b = \frac{a\sqrt{2} - 1}{a}$, we have $\frac{a^2b^2-2a^2b+2a^2+2ab-2a+1}{a^2b+a} = 2\sqrt{2} - 2$.

Thus, the minimum is $2\sqrt{2} - 2$.